# Why does pm4py.view doesn't generate any image

Tags: data-mining, event-log

For a business process discovery task, I am trying to generate a process model, following pm4py python library. Here's a sample code:

```
!pip install pm4py
import pm4py

log = pm4py.read_xes('/content/running-example.xes')

process_model, initial_marking, final_marking = pm4py.discover_petri_net_inductive(log)

pm4py.view_petri_net(process_model, initial_marking, final_marking, format="svg")
```

However, I get output as:

```
parsing log, completed traces :: 100%
6/6 [00:00<00:00, 121.77it/s]
```

But no image as is expected from the website: https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/getting-started-page#discovery

Being relatively new to the world of python, what I learnt from other coders' suggestions here on SO that always read in depth the source code in case of open source libraries.

Here is pm4py visual links:
https://github.com/pm4py/pm4py-core/blob/afee8b0932283b8f8f02dd2b6cc0968a1f1cc723/pm4py/visualization/process_tree/visualizer.py#L69

and specifically for my example:
https://github.com/pm4py/pm4py-core/blob/afee8b0932283b8f8f02dd2b6cc0968a1f1cc723/pm4py/vis.py#L17

But I am not able to figure out how to manipulate it.

Can someone please point out the problem to me and help me generate the views. Also, if anyone has done business process generations before, maybe if you could suggest me any libraries or techniques to analyse event-logs data it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

to visualize the process models mined in PM4Py, make sure that you have graphviz installed on your computer.

see https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/install for more information on this.

Comment: I am using colab - and graphviz is already installed there